# DataNucleus + JDO : Retrieve an object with Composite Key (error:NoSuchElementException)

Tags: java, hbase, jdo, datanucleus, nosuchelementexception

I have a ComposedIdKey class that I use to create a composite key for Customer class. 
I can successfully insert this object in Hbase with composite key.
However, when I try to access that object get the following message:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:349)
        at DN_Schema.ComposedIdKey.<init>(ComposedIdKey.java:26)
        at DN_Schema.Customer_JDO3.dnNewObjectIdInstance(Customer_JDO3.java)
        at org.datanucleus.enhancer.EnhancementHelper.newObjectIdInstance(EnhancementHelper.java:221)
        at org.datanucleus.identity.IdentityManagerImpl.getApplicationId(IdentityManagerImpl.java:479)
        at org.datanucleus.ExecutionContextImpl.newObjectId(ExecutionContextImpl.java:3729)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.newObjectIdInstance(JDOPersistenceManager.java:1595)
        at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.getObjectById(JDOPersistenceManager.java:1723)
        at Performance.DataNucleusPerfo.Read_Hbase(DataNucleusPerfo.java:109)
```

**the compososedIdKey**

```
public class ComposedIdKey implements Serializable
{
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public String dateOfBirth;

    public ComposedIdKey ()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Constructor accepting same input as generated by toString().
     */
    public ComposedIdKey(String value)
    {
        StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer (value, "::");
        token.nextToken();               // className
        this.firstName = token.nextToken(); // field1
        this.lastName = token.nextToken(); // field2l
        this.dateOfBirth = token.nextToken(); // filed3
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        if (obj == this)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof ComposedIdKey))
        {
            return false;
        }
        ComposedIdKey c = (ComposedIdKey)obj;

        return firstName.equals(c.firstName) && lastName.equals(c.lastName) && dateOfBirth.equals(c.dateOfBirth);
    }

    public int hashCode ()
    {
        return this.firstName.hashCode() ^ this.lastName.hashCode() ^ this.dateOfBirth.hashCode() ;
    }

    public String toString ()
    {
        // Give output expected by String constructor
        return this.getClass().getName() + "::"  + this.firstName + "::" + this.lastName + "::" + this.dateOfBirth;
    }
}
```

**The code that i use  to get the object :**

```
Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction();
        System.out.println("Retrieving Customer");
        Customer_JDO3 teste = null;
     try
            {
                tx.begin();
                teste = pm.getObjectById(Customer_JDO3.class,"10-10-10DataNucleus");
```

The rowkey in Hbase appears **10-10-10DataNucleus**

**What can I be doing wrong?**
Thanks

Comment: the error is thrown from your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you try to split the entry of the ctor with "::" but the entry doesn't contain such chars.

Comment: Thanks @mvera , The  was this and missing add the name of the class. Besides that the order has to be according to the String returned in Class ComposedIdKey .` "ComposedIdKey::Data::Nucleus::10-10-10`